# How to get subscribed element in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am facing one problem in my code.

following is the structure of my code.

```
this.dataService.currentSearchResult.subscribe(topics => {
      this.topics = topics;
      console.log(this.topics);
      var topicdetails;
     console.log("Hello Jayesh Vyas Developer111"+this.topics[0].attributes.TopicId);
}
```

in the above code, I want to print the zero index data as topic id but I am getting the following error when I am printing the zero index topic in the console.

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
at SafeSubscriber._next (topic.component.ts:95)
at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:185)
at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:124)
at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
at BehaviorSubject._subscribe (BehaviorSubject.js:14)
at BehaviorSubject._trySubscribe (Observable.js:42)
at BehaviorSubject._trySubscribe (Subject.js:81)
at BehaviorSubject.subscribe (Observable.js:28)
at Observable._subscribe (Observable.js:76)
```

and in the `topics`, the data format is as below mentioned.

```
[
  {
    "attributes": {
      "User": "Administrator",
      "ObjNumber": "0000000081",
      "ObjName": "2 Wheeler bike.",
      "ObjType": "Part",
      "TopicId": "160929"
    },
    "attributes": {
      "User": "Administrator",
      "ObjNumber": "0000000081",
      "ObjName": "2 Wheeler bike.",
      "ObjType": "Part",
      "TopicId": "160930"
    },
    "attributes": {
      "User": "Administrator",
      "ObjNumber": "0000000081",
      "ObjName": "2 Wheeler bike.",
      "ObjType": "Part",
      "TopicId": "160931"
    }
  }
]
```

I am trying to getting the zero index topicid but after running the code it is giving the above-mentioned error.

can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Cannot read property data but in the code you showing you don't use property data of an any object, can you show topic.component.ts:95

Comment: @Angular please see the updated post. line number 95 is the one in which I am printing the console.

Comment: is the data format you pasted above actually what is outputted via the **console.log(this.topics);** line of code?

Comment: @ChiragPatel Yes it is the same but in the next sentence when I am printing the zero index topic I am getting the error

Comment: The json you posted is not valid because : 1. There is an extra `,` after each TopicId 2. There are duplicate keys `attributes`

Comment: @NicholasK Please ignore that extra ' , '

Comment: I suspect that the duplicate keys are causing the issue..

Comment: agree with what @NicholasK said

Comment: No, I don't think this is the issue @ChiragPatel

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz to replicate the issue? I've tried to replicate your issue [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-mapping-arr-resp-iju6du) - the code you've shared seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be something wrong with your response JSON, therefore it cannot be automatically converted to an array. If you check your JSON in this link you will be able to verify the error:

[JSON formatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

If I undestand correctly what you are trying to achieve with the JSON, it should be something like this:

```
[
{
    "attributes": {
      "User": "Administrator",
      "ObjNumber": "0000000081",
      "ObjName": "2 Wheeler bike.",
      "ObjType": "Part",
      "TopicId": "160929"
    }
},
{
    "attributes": {
      "User": "Administrator",
      "ObjNumber": "0000000081",
      "ObjName": "2 Wheeler bike.",
      "ObjType": "Part",
      "TopicId": "160930"
    }
},
{
    "attributes": {
      "User": "Administrator",
      "ObjNumber": "0000000081",
      "ObjName": "2 Wheeler bike.",
      "ObjType": "Part",
      "TopicId": "160931"
    }
}
]
```